# JSON file does not show up when I push a button

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get my JSON file to show up on the page when I push a button, but for some reason code does not get the file.

When I press the button it should show 4 arrays.

```js
var autotila = document.getElementById("autolista")
var nappi = document.getElementById("nappi");

nappi.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var auto = new XMLHttpRequest();
  auto.open('GET', 'cars.json');
  auto.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(auto.responseText);
    lisaahtml(ourData);
  };
  auto.send();
});


function lisaahtml(data) {
  var htmlpatka = "";
  for (i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
    htmlpatka += "<p>" + data[i].manufacturer + "," + data[i].model + "," + data[i].price + "," + data[i].wiki + "</p>";
  }
  autotila.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlpatka)
}
```

```html
<button id="nappi" value="nappi" type="button">Paina</button>
<div id="autolista"></div>
```

```
{
    "data" : [{ 
        "manufacturer" : "Porsche",
        "model" : "911",
        "price" : 135000,
        "quality" : [{ 
            "name" : "overall",
            "rating" : 3
        },{ 
            "name" : "mechanical",
            "rating" : 4
        },{ 
            "name" : "powertrain",
            "rating" : 2
        },{ 
            "name" : "body",
            "rating" : 4
        },{ 
            "name" : "interior",
            "rating" : 3
        },{ 
            "name" : "accessories",
            "rating" : 2
        }],
        "wiki" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_997"
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any console errors? Also you should use the `fetch` api instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, but that's not a massive issue :)

Comment: Are you loading your HTML from file system?

Comment: What's in the JSON file?

Comment: data.lenght is incorrect, data.length

Comment: No, not a single error.

All the HTML is in the same file, so i would sayy no :D

I edited JSON to OP.

Comment: have you checked whether you're getting the data you expect? Does the AJAX request complete successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Looks lie there is a typo:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

Comment: I think this is the most common typo ever made in programming

Comment: I fixed that, but it did not help. Still no errors at log

Answer (score 0):

**pass data.length**

```
  var autotila = document.getElementById("autolista")
    var nappi = document.getElementById("nappi");

    nappi.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var auto = new XMLHttpRequest();
      auto.open('GET', 'cars.json');
      auto.onload = function() {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(auto.responseText);
        lisaahtml(ourData);
      };
      auto.send();
    });


    function lisaahtml(data) {
      var htmlpatka = "";
      for (i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {<<<-----  data.length
        htmlpatka += "<p>" + data[i].manufacturer + "," + data[i].model + "," + data[i].price + "," + data[i].wiki + "</p>";
      }
      autotila.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlpatka)
    }
```